# Refering to subdomain name when using domain ip number

Tags: apache, dns, ip

Apologies if this question is not correct.

I have a local development machine with:

1. a rest server project been accessed by `localhost`
2. and an ajax javascript project been accessed by `app.localhost`.

Both are been served by an Apache server.

I have a deployment VPS with static ip, currently no DNS name. Before I set a domain name, is there a way to access the sub domain with the ip address, so to test the ajax project from outside ?

For example:

- On local machine I access it via `app.localhost`
- On VPS ip = 127.0.0.1, can I access it with something like `app.127.0.0.1` ?

Is there a syntax or an option to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a way to do this. Assuming you have two different VirtualHost config as below

```
<VirtulHost *:80>ServerName main.domain.name...</VirtualHost>
```

And

```
<VirtulHost *:80>ServerName sub.domain.name...</VirtualHost>
```

Put these two entries in a [host file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) of machine on which you are performing testing.

```
ip of VPS   main.domain.name
ip of VPS   sub.domain.name
```

Go to your [LAN Settings](http://jzvb4w.bay.livefilestore.com/y1pFFzFU8lHkXPfYDedlBciYZHuC0Z0xGgA3zAn3SF03uR2nRVbEBcmYM2mblFZM07ZMi3nigjwu-wxa6JzDWkVnTbaBuL-z9ji/Internet%20Options.png) on IE and make sure all options under `Automatic Configuration` and `Proxy Server`are unchecked.

Restart IE and try to access both domains.

Hope that helps!

Comment: First, thank you.
That is what I do on my local machine. In the conf file the domain name is "app.localhost"
But it does not work on the remote machine. When I enter the ip address in firefox, I can't add "app" to the ip address. This only works when testing within the remote mechine like I do on the local machine. I am trying to access the site on the remote machine via browser.

Comment: Disregard my first comment. I read your answer a second time and now I understand. Thank you very much. On my local machine I have changed the host file so it will be like a 'private dns' as you suggested. I assume this is working because Apache on the server knows the domain name I use through the request header? Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, that is correct. Apache understands this from host field in a request header.